# recyclerview getting refreshed on adding new item to list

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview which holds a cardview, inside cardview i have bunch of radio buttons and 2 time picker and 2 textview.i need to add new cards to recyclerview dynamically on click of button. i implemented a adapte for that and on click of button item is adding to list.

the proble is when i add a card and change time or select radio button, then click on add button again the old card getting refteshed and dta which i have entered is gone, how can i get it

and i have some screenshots how it works

please help me to fix this, thank you

here is my code:

**adapter code**

```
@Override
    public LabourWorkAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.labour_work_card, parent, false);
    return new LabourWorkAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final LabourWorkAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final LabourWorkList listItem = labourWork.get(position);

    holder.fromTime.setText(listItem.getFromDate());
    holder.toTime.setText(listItem.getToDate());

    //        holder.cDay.setText(listItem.getFullDay());
    holder.fromTimePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    int hour_x = 0;
    int minute_x = 0;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(context, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
    String hr, mn, timeMode = "AM";
    if (selectedHour > 12){
    selectedHour = selectedHour-12;
    timeMode = "PM";
    }
    if (selectedHour < 10){
    hr = "0"+selectedHour;
    }else{
    hr = ""+selectedHour;
    }
    if (selectedMinute < 10){
    mn = "0"+selectedMinute;
    }else{
    mn = ""+selectedMinute;
    }
    holder.fromTime.setText( hr + ":" + mn + timeMode);
    }
    }, hour_x, minute_x, false);
    mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
    mTimePicker.show();
    }
    });

    holder.toTimePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    int hour_x = 0;
    int minute_x = 0;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(context, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
    String hr, mn, timeMode = "AM";
    if (selectedHour > 12){
    selectedHour = selectedHour-12;
    timeMode = "PM";
    }
    if (selectedHour < 10){
    hr = "0"+selectedHour;
    }else{
    hr = ""+selectedHour;
    }
    if (selectedMinute < 10){
    mn = "0"+selectedMinute;
    }else{
    mn = ""+selectedMinute;
    }
    holder.toTime.setText( hr + ":" + mn + timeMode);
    }
    }, hour_x, minute_x, false);
    mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
    mTimePicker.show();
    }
    });

    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    labourWork.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, labourWork.size());
    CharSequence text = "Position "+ position;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
    }
    });
    //        holder.labourWorkDay


    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
    return labourWork.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView fromTime, toTime;
    Button fromTimePicker, toTimePicker;
    ImageView delete;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    fromTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fromTime);
    toTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.toTime);
    fromTimePicker = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fromTimePicker);
    toTimePicker = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.toTimePicker);
    delete = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteLabourCard);
    }
    }
```

**button click listener**

```
rId.setText(tempLabourId);

recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.workDetailsRecycler);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

workList = new ArrayList<>();

addItem = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addLabor);

addItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
addToRecyclerView(sPosition);
sPosition++;
}
});


public void addToRecyclerView(int position){
LabourWorkList listItem = new LabourWorkList(position);
recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
workList.add(listItem);

adapter = new LabourWorkAdapter(workList, LabourWork.this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. In particular, your code has a compiler error because there are no classes. Also please fix the formatting.

Comment: you could also look at the adapters various methods that suits your requirement instead of using just `notifyDataSetChanged()`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Recyclerview` is getting refreshed every time, because you are setting adapter every time when you add new item and call `notifyDataSetChanged` method.

To resolve this, set adapter only once then add new item to list and call

```
adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(lastListSize, newListSize);
```